# Missing number in sequenze

Tags: pattern-recognition

A friend posted this an hour ago and it kept me busy since. Anybody has a clue what the missing number is? I understand multiple outcomes are possible but i cannot find any. There is also a possibility he is joking with me, he sent a picture with this question on a sheet of paper. An explanation on how you found it would be neat.

$$12/84/ \_\_\_ /15626$$

Comment: There's a unique quadratic function whose graph passes through the points $(1,12)$, $(2,84)$, and $(4,15626)$. It also passes through the point $(3,15866/3)$.  Did you try asking your friend if he is joking with you?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I asked him if it is solvable.

Comment: I cant possibly add more info and it is a mathematical problem... So why the downvote?

Comment: I am not sure it is a mathematical problem.  Finding patterns in partial sequences of numbers can be part of mathematics, but isn't necessarily mathematics. Here there is no mathematical context.   (By the way, http://oeis.org is a great place to check when there is reason to believe you have a start to a sequence that might be known.  I don't expect it to help in this case.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A suggestion :
\begin{array}{cc}
2^3+4&12\\
3^4+3&84\\
4^5+2&1026\\
5^6+1&15626\\
\end{array}

Comment: How in the world did you find this?

Comment: @alex.jordan I will make that my next question :)

Comment: @alex.jordan: factoring $15626$, $15626-1$ and searching a pattern...

Answer (score 0):

There are literally an infinite number of patterns that can be made out of this one:

If the third number is 1 the pattern can be demonstrated by

$$y(x) = \frac{15686}{6}x^3 - 8009x^2 + \frac{32623}{6}x + 12$$

If the third number is instead 2 the pattern can still be locked in by

$$ y(x) = \frac{7930}{3}x^3 - 8007x^2 + \frac{16307}{3}x + 12$$

and I can endlessly change the value of the third number and still prove there is a pattern.

Did your friend give any additional information to the type of pattern he/she wanted? Otherwise you can just mess with him/her and give both of these as valid answers